# 3-Body Phase in a $2\rightarrow 3$ scattering

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, scattering, phase-space, scattering-cross-section

[image]
I am trying to calculate Bethe-Heitler cross section for pair production. I am starting from the well known formula 
\begin{equation}
d\sigma=\cfrac{1}{2E_1 2E_p}\vert M_0\vert^2(2\pi)^4\delta^4(p_1+p-p'-p_3-p_4)\cfrac{1}{(2\pi)^9}\cfrac{d^3p'}{2E_{p'}}\cfrac{d^3p_3}{2E_{3}}\cfrac{d^3p_4}{2E_{4}}
\end{equation}
doing the three integration to get rid of some delta function we end up with
\begin{equation*}
d\sigma=\cfrac{1}{32E_\gamma E_pE_p'}\vert M_0\vert^2\delta(E_\gamma+E_p-E_{p'}-E_3-E_4)\cfrac{1}{(2\pi)^5}\cfrac{{p_3}^2dp_3d\Omega_3}{E_{3}}\cfrac{{p_4}^2dp_4d\Omega_4}{E_{4}}
\end{equation*}
we want to change the integration over the amplitude of the momentum to the energy. This can be done by the energy momentum relation
\begin{equation*}
E^2=p^2+m^2\Rightarrow pdp=EdE\Rightarrow p^2dp=pEdE
\end{equation*}
Thus returning back we have 
\begin{equation}
d\sigma=\cfrac{p_3p_4}{32(2\pi)^5E_\gamma E_pE_p'}\vert M_0\vert^2\delta(E_\gamma+E_p-E_{p'}-E_3-E_4)dE_3d\Omega_3dE_4d\Omega_4
\end{equation}
After getting rid of the final delta function we end up with
\begin{equation}
d\sigma=\cfrac{p_3p_4}{32(2\pi)^5E_1 E_pE_p'}\vert 
M_0\vert^2d\Omega_3d\Omega_4 dE_4
\end{equation}
Where $E_{p'}$ can be found from the energy conservation. Also we are in proton's rest frame of reference thus $E_p=M$.

My question is that after comparing my result with papers, it seems that I miss a factor of $2$ somewhere and I don't know where I have done wrong.